# Accusative after "sein"

Tags: grammatical-case

I’m lost with the verb *sein*. I read on multiple websites and according to what I have learned, *sein* is always followed by nominative.

Examples:

> Er ist der Mann.
>   Er ist ein großer Mann.

not

> * Er ist den Mann.
>   * Er ist einen großen Mann.

But does one say the following?

> Es ist nächsten Sommer.
>   Es ist letzten Sommer gewesen.

Shouldn’t it be:

> Es ist nächster Sommer.

My question is, why is it *nächsten* and not *nächster?* And is *sein* always followed by nominative? I’m wondering because it seems like dative is used instead of nominative in the following sentence:

> Das ist mir egal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise that *sein* is always followed by nominative is wrong. You don't even need a substantive, e.g. "Ich bin müde.".

You could say that *sein* is always accompanied by nominative; but seriously, there is (almost) always a nominative because the subject, which is obligatory, is in nominative. And in case someone raises objection to this statement: yes, there are some exceptions (e.g. "Mir ist kalt."), but this is irrelevant to your question.

So, *sein* is a verb that has quite a few definitions. This verb can even be used as copula, auxiliary and full verb.

One definition basically expresses an equality between two things. A sentence like "Ich bin Lehrer." means, kinda, 'I equal teacher'. In that case both parts have to be in the same case. Since *I* is in nominative (as it is the subject of the sentence), *Lehrer* is in nominative, too.
And this applies to your first example.

Another definition for *sein* is that something occurs at a certain place or at a certain time. Such a sentence doesn't have a second substantive whatsoever, so obviously there can't be another one in nominative. Your other example (i.e. "Es ist nächsten Sommer.") fits into this group.

The past form of that sentence (i.e. "Es ist letzten Sommer gewesen") is comprised of two *sein*. The former one is the auxiliary verb for the present perfect, the latter one is the past participle of *sein*, expressing yet again that something occurs at a certain time. There's no second substantive, hence there's not another nominative.

The full story about *sein* is sheer endless. But if I haven't missed anything, the only case with two nominatives is the equality that I talked about above. So, only when you can apply 'A equals B', the substantive following *sein* is in nominative.

Comment: Oh, I see! Just out of curiosity, something like, "Wo ist das Bier," would that also be, "Wo equals Bier"? Because it would make sense with the example you provided, "Ich bin Lehrer - I equal Lehrer." Another example would be, "Das Buch ist meins". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Adverbials that describe a period of time contain nouns use the accusative ([Adverbialkasus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung#Substantive)). This is why "nächsten Sommer" always stays in the accusative, no matter what happens to the subject, direct object and indirect object:

> Ich (Nom.) gebe **nächsten Sommer** meinem Freund (Dat.) meinen Stadtplan. (Akk.)
>
> Mein Stadtplan (Nom.) wird **nächsten Sommer** von mir meinem Freund (Dat) gegeben.

The same applies to sentences of the form "X (Nom.) ist Y (Nom.)":

> Er (Nom.) ist ein großer Mann. (Nom.)
>
> Er (Nom.) ist **nächsten Sommer** ein großer Mann. (Nom).

And the same applies to "Es ist gewesen" in the sense of "Es ist passiert":

> Es ist **letzten Sommer** passiert.
>
> Es ist **letzen Sommer** gewesen.

(This construction doesn't really work with the Präsens, "Es ist nächsten Sommer" makes no sense, though you can say "Es passiert nächsten Sommer" in the sense of "Es wird nächsten Sommer passieren". You can also say "Es wird nächsten Sommer/im nächsten Sommer sein").

2) It's also possible to have sentences of the form "X ist Y" where Y is not a noun, but (formally) an adverb (though there's a number of different names for it): "Dieses Auto ist grün", "Es ist egal". As Y is not a noun, of course it doesn't have a case.

So there is no rule "*sein* is always followed by the nominative". The correct rule is: "if two objects X and Y are described as equal using *sein*, then both are in the nominative".

And for some expressions, you can add an indirect object to *sein*: "Mir ist kalt", "das ist mir egal". Sometimes that even works for two nouns: "Das ist mir eine Lehre".

Comment: you mixed up the cases. If one described a period of time, it would read *Es ist den letzten Sommer lang regnerisch gewesen.* That would need accusative for the adverbial. Points in time are put in genitive or (everyday usage) dative.

Comment: @Janka: No, I didn't mix up cases. Points in time are indeed genitive ("eines Tages"), but periods of time are accusative ("den ganzen Tag"); read e.g. the linked wikipedia article.

Comment: @Janka Will it be correct sentence if I write "Es ist im nächsten Sommer." ?

Comment: Yes. Present tense may also tell the future if there are time markers.

Answer (score -1):

In *Es ist letzten Sommer gewesen*, the subject isn't *letzten Sommer* but **Es**.

**Es** is a fill-in subject used when you need something in nominative – as with *sein*.

Comment: Hm, since "Er" in "Er ist der Mann" is also the subject, how do the examples differ?

Comment: The OPs premise was: *sein is followed by nominative* and that premise is wrong. The rule is *sein goes with nominative*. Usually the subject of a sentence comes first, as in English, but the subject may have additional qualifiers which come after *sein*. As these qualifiers belong to the subject, they have to be marked as such and thus, put into nominative case. *Letzten Sommer* however, does not qualify *Es* further. Because it is an adverbial of time, which goes with the verb, as the name suggests.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I don't understand why would, "Es," be the subject here, but not "Er," in the other example?

Comment: Both *Es* and *Er* are the subject. In "*Er ist der Mann*", *der Mann* are additional qualifiers to *Er*. They are in nominative because of that. They aren't the subject.

Comment: As said, forget that "rule" *sein is followed by nominative*. Don't know who spread this but it is wrong. *Sein is with nominative* is correct. Because for the action of *sein*, you don't need an object. As in English.

Comment: Excuse my lack of understanding, but if there is no need for an object with "Sein" and according to Pons dictionary, "Sein", is an intransitive verb, what is the point of declining "Nächste" then to "Nächsten," or "Letzte" to "Letzten"?

Comment: Please read what I have wrote. Exactly what your PONS says. ***Because for the action of sein, you don't need an object.*** The reason why it is declined lies in the function of case for adverbials. Please consider the full sentence *Es ist **im** letzten Sommer gewesen.*, as your example is a shorter form, leaving out the *im*. *im* is short for *in dem*, which denotes a position (in time) by using the **dative**.