# Two different case of determiner and adjective before individual noun

Tags: grammatical-case

The original sentence will found in second answer of [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32472/accusative-after-sein) question thread.

> Original sentence: 1. Es wird nächsten Sommer/im nächsten Sommer sein.

I have written the sentence below only with Preposition + Article

> 2. Es wird im nächsten Sommer sein.

In the 2nd sentence the determiner **im = in + dem(Dativ)** and **adjective nächsten (accusative)** are in two different case before the noun (Sommer),

So my question is: Is it appropriate to have two different case of determiner and adjective before an individual noun which they both modify?

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi

Answer (score 2):

*Nächsten* in the dative case in *im nächsten Sommer*, see http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/adjectives/adjective-declensions for declension tables of adjectives + nouns.