# "Herbert ist ein guter Freund (m) von mir.": the declension rules don't match the answer sheet in nthuleen's exercise sheet

Tags: grammar-identification, declension

In one of [nthuleen's exercise sheets](https://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/adjektivendungen2.html), it is given that (question 1.4, see the answer sheet)

> Herbert ist ein gut**er** Freund (m) von mir.

However, "Freund" is a direct object in this sentence, hence it is an accusative case. According to [the declension table of Laura](https://germanwithlaura.com/declension/#declined-nouns), it should have been

> Herbert ist einen guten Freund (m) von mir.

But the answer key declines the adjective as if it is a nominative case. Am I missing something in here or is the answer sheet wrong?

Comment: And once again a learner of German has been lead astray by the term "direct object". And by the way, no, *Freund* is not a direct object. It is actually no object at all.

Comment: @RHa Is there a better way to think about the cases in German than thinking about direct/indirect object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, when "sein" is the main verb and it used to mean one thing is equal to another, i.e "X ist Y", or to describe a feature of something, "Y" is also becomes [nominative case.](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32479/43272)

Comment: Yes. And that's why it is not the "direct object". Such thing does not exist in German; it is a term for English grammar which does not translate exactly to German. Any rule concerning these will have exceptions.

Comment: It's best to use "accusative object" and "dative object" for German, since the "direct/indirect" distinction isn't reliable in German. I'd call *guter Freund* here a "predicate object", and unlike English these match the case of the other noun. So with *sein* both are nominative: *Ich bin ein Berliner* not *Ich bin einen Berliner*. With *nennen* both are accusative: "Ich nenne ihn einen Berliner."